# Instead of delete trigger performance

Tags: trigger, sql-server-2019, dml

We have 3rd party tool which is deleting data via below parametrize query:

```
delete from [sap].[PRCD_ELEMENTS]
where [rowid] = @P1
```

Table contains around 3 billions of records and is partitioned by different `nvarchar(10)` column. We have non clustered index on `rowid` (`rowid` is not a part of PK/clustered index).

We could have 200 000 deletes per minute which means above query will be executed in one sessions with different `rowid` in a loop.

I am thinking to speed it up and create `instead of delete` trigger which will be collecting deleted records with partitioned column. Also create job which will be executed every 1 minute which will be deleting collected records via join with new table with `rowid` and `partition column`. Something like this:

```
delete prcd
from [sap].[PRCD_ELEMENTS] prcd inner join 
dbo.newTableWithDeleteTriggerValues d on prcd.rowid = d.rowid and prcd.partitioned_column = d.partitioned_column
```

The question is what is the performance of instead of delete trigger and will handle this kind of problem.

Comment: What about putting all the rowids into an indexed temp table or TVP, then doing a joined delete

Comment: @Charlieface I can not change delete query. It is 3rd party tool which is preparing delete query. Or you mean indexed temp table in instead of delete trigger ?

Comment: Is the non-clustered `rowid` index partitioned? Is it unique?

Comment: @DanGuzman non-clustered index is partitioned but not unique

Comment: Is the database also third party? Is the vendor for the database and the tool the same?

Comment: @rois No, we have control on database. It is sql server 2019 database